# Including a value in the first three elements of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the following code to get an array of some values.

```
<?php

$sms = array();
foreach($contact_number as $value) {    

    $sms[] = array($value, $message);       

}   

 var_dump($sms);
```

What I am trying to do now is include a variable `$abc = "From Charlie Sheen";` with `$message` in the first 3 elements of the above array, so that when the first three message appears I can see "From Charlie Sheen" at the end of the original message.

Could you please tell me how to solve this problem (its better if I don't have to make any change in the above array; I wish to add a new line of code to solve this problem)

The output of `var_dump($sms);` is :

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(3) "123"
        [1]=> string(15) "This is Message"
    }
    [1]=> array(2) {
        [0]=> string(3) "456"
        [1]=> string(15) "This is Message"
    }
}
```

Comment: So right now, you're giving the same message to all of the contact numbers. Is this for something like war dialing/texting or is this going to create a log?

Comment: Also contact numbers aren't unique so they shouldn't be used as a unique identifier... eg. Mom and Dad have the same home contact number.

Comment: @cpattersonv1 I am trying to create an application to send bulk sms :)

Comment: I am just throwing my data to my sms service provider using an api :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sms = array();
$toAdd = 3;
foreach($contact_number as $value) {
    if($toAdd > 0) {
        $sms[] = array($value, $message . 'charlie bla bla');       
       --$toAdd;
    } else {
        $sms[] = array($value, $message);
    }
}
```

Or shorter :

```
$sms = array();
for($toAdd = 3, $i = 0, $l = count($contact_number); $i < $l; --$toAdd, ++$i)
    $sms[] = array($value, $toAdd > 0 ? $message . 'charlie bla bla' : $message);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I tried your first code.. In the first message I am getting From Charlie Sheen once, in the second message I get From Charlie Sheen twice and in the third message I get From charlie Sheen thrice.. and your code is adding From Charlie Sheen in all the array elements.

Comment: Well i was assuming that you were setting the value of $message every loop. If you are not then each loop of the first code would add charlie to the message, that's why you get it one more time every loop.
Edited my codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it while creating the array by adding a counter

```
<?php

  $sms = array();
  $counter = 0;
  foreach($contact_number as $value) {    
     if($counter < 3) { $message .= " From Charlie Sheen"; }

     $sms[] = array($value, $message);       

     $counter++;
  }   

  var_dump($sms);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your code, but its not working properly. In the first message I am getting `From Charlie Sheen` once, in the second message I get `From Charlie Sheen` twice and in the third message I get `From charlie Sheen` thrice.. and your code is adding `From Charlie Sheen` in all the array elements. Thanks

Comment: This should really be a for statement instead of foreach if you're going to try this approach.

Comment: Black_belt, I assumed that $message would be reset every time.  If not, then the above approach wouldn't work.  @cpattersonv, I agree, a for loop would work well here.  The foreach would work for associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to tell from the example what you're doing with this... Remember that other contact numbers aren't necessarily unique, but mobile numbers *should* be. If you're making a logging system of sorts:

```
<?php

    $cell_numbers = array(
    '000-555-1212'=>'Charlie Sheen',
    '800-333-4475'=>'Mary Poppins'
    );

    $sms = array();

    //Number from the person texting
    $inbound = $_POST['number'];

    //Message from the person texting
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if(!empty($cell_numbers[$inbound])){
        $sms[][$number]=$message;   
    }

    foreach($sms as $key=>$tempArr){

       foreach($sms[$key] as $tNum=>$tMes){
           echo "Message from ".$cell_numbers[$tNum]." - $tMes\n";
       }
    }

?>
```

If you're making a war text e-mailer app, then you could do this:

```
<?php
    $contacts = array(
    0=>array(
    'number'=>'000-555-1212',
    'name'=>'Charlie Sheen',
    'carrier'=>'Sprint'),
    1=>array(
    'number'=>'800-333-4475',
    'name'=>'Mary Poppins',
    'carrier'=>'ATT'),
    );

    $carriers = array(
    'ATT'=>'txt.att.net',
    'Sprint'=>'messaging.sprintpcs.com',
    'T-Mobile'=>'tomomail.net',
    'Virgin'=>'vmobl.com',
    'Verizon'=>'vtext.com',
    );

    $message = 'Do I know you?';
    $sms = array();

    foreach ($contacts as $key=>$tempArr){

        $to = $contacts[$key]['number'].'@'.$carriers[$contacts[$key]['carrier']];
        if(mail("$to","SMS","$message",$headers = 'From: Tom Hanks <911@vtext.com>' . "\r\n")){
        $SMS[$to] = 'yes';  
        } else {
        $SMS[$to] = 'failed';
        }

    }

?>
```